# How to customize supabase email?

Tags: html, email, authentication, supabase

My application leverages supabase's magic link for user authentication.

It works great but the email looks pretty basic. That's what it looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to edit this email template?

I'd like to change the language and to add some customized content like my app's logo.

Comment: There's also [other way for self-hosted supabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75236832/how-to-customize-supabase-selfhosted-on-docker-email?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can customize any of these emails with the link below (for Supabase hosted):

https://app.supabase.com/project/_/auth/templates

[image]

You can customize these emails like you would for any email client using HTML tags, pictures, etc.

You can use pictures in base64 or even link them to your website(some people use linked pictures to track if the email was open or not).