# How to customize supabase (selfhosted on docker) email?

Tags: docker, supabase

Hi I can't change the template of the emails sent from supabase, I've tried everything.
It works great but I would like to be able to customize it.

the non-self hosted solution (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73312777/how-to-customize-supabase-email?newreg=134152e2747047fd84fe12fd2151ae2a) is different)

[email screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhTCc.png)

Is there a way to edit this email template?

I searched on the documentation in general, googling and looking for solutions on github. I would like a solution on how to set it up, currently I have not been able to get results.

Answer (score 0):

There's one - to config GoTrue (after reading [documentation>e-mail](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue)) through env:

Here's the example from [self-hosting tutorial](https://dev.to/chronsyn/self-hosting-with-supabase-1aii):

```
# Email templates
# Invite user - provide a URL to a HTML or Text template
GOTRUE_MAILER_TEMPLATES_INVITE=https://example.com/path/to/your/invite/template.html

# Confirm registration - provide a URL to a HTML or Text template
GOTRUE_MAILER_TEMPLATES_CONFIRMATION=https://example.com/path/to/your/confirmation/template.html

# Password recovery - provide a URL to a HTML or Text template
GOTRUE_MAILER_TEMPLATES_RECOVERY=https://example.com/path/to/your/password_reset/template.HTML

# Magic link - provide a URL to a HTML or Text template
GOTRUE_MAILER_TEMPLATES_MAGIC_LINK=https://example.com/path/to/your/magic_link/template.html
```